# Unable to run a wrapper to return a member function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17

I need to pass a **pointer to a non-static member function** to an external library. The member functions use object-specific variables, so I cannot make them *static*. However, I can obtain the `this` pointer that points to the current object. So I decided to write a wrapper which can use the `this` pointer to return a member function pointer. But I am unable to get C++ to stop throwing errors. Could I get some help?

I have already tried 
1) returning `&classname::functionname`
2) returning `functionname`
3) typecasting to a `void` pointer.
But none of these work. That is why I decided on a wrapper.

```cpp
// Member function 1 of class MyClass
// that uses object-specific variables
// and hence cannot be made static
template<typename T> vector<T> MyClass<T>::dxBydt(T x, vector<T> y){
    ...
    ...
    return dxdt;
}

// Member function 2 of class MyClass
// that uses object-specific variables
// and hence cannot be made static
template<typename T> vector<T> MyClass<T>::res(Matrix<T> bc){
    ...
    ...
    return r;
}
// ===================

// Wrapper for member function 1
template<typename T> vector<T> (MyClass<T>::*dxBydt_wrapper(void* pointerToObject)) (T, vector<T>) {
    MyClass<T>* thisObject = (MyClass<T>*) pointerToObject;
    return thisObject->*dxBydt;
}

// Wrapper for member function 2
template<typename T> VectorXm<T>  (MyClass<T>::*res_wrapper(void* pointerToObject))(Matrix<T>){
    MyClass<T>* thisObject = (MyClass<T>*) pointerToObject;
    return thisObject->*res;
}

// Where the action happens
template<typename T> Solution<T> MyClass<T>::solve(){
    ...
    ...
    ...

    // odeSolver is external and takes two free function pointers
    // but throws errors with member function pointers
    solution = odeSolver<T>(..., dxBydt_wrapper(this), res_wrapper(this), ...);
    return solution;
}
```

I get the errors
1. `error: 'dxBydt' was not declared in this scope` and
2. `error: 'res' was not declared in this scope`.

Nevertheless, `thisObject` is supposed to have access to both the above functions.

Could you please lead me to a solution so that this wrapper successfully  returns a function pointer?

Comment: If `odeSolver` doesn't provide a way to pass the `this` pointer then there isn't much you can do, if `odeSolver` is single threaded you can use a thread local global variable to store `this`. We need a [mcve] to help further.

Comment: Does it accept exactly C-style pointers to functions? Member functions cannot be cast to those, so you'll need auxiliary functions that invoke this method on a global object.